# Completable Future Call 3 Methods in Parallel

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I recently ran into an out of memory issue while using completable futures because there was too much garbage collection occuring and want to make sure I'm properly using CompletableFutures.

I have 3 services which I want to call in parallel. Right now I have the following:

```
final CompletableFuture<Void> f1 = runAsync(() -> m1.call(arg1, arg2, arg3));
final CompletableFuture<Void> f2 = runAsync(() -> m2.call(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4));
final CompletableFuture<Void> f3 = runAsync(() -> m3.call(arg1, arg2, arg3));
```

I then loop over the futures and call .get() on each. I've also seen an example with the following:

```
final CompletableFuture<Void> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> m1.call(arg1, arg2, arg3)),
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> m2.call(arg1, arg2, arg3),
            CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> m3.call(arg1, arg2, arg3))
    );
```

And then calls .join()

What is the proper way to go about this?

The error I'm receiving points to the .get() line on one of the completable futures.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
```

Comment: The OutOfMemoryError means that the GC needs to much time to clean up. This can happen if you create to many objects very fast. **Sometimes** increasing the heap memory may help.

Comment: You don’t get an `OutOfMemoryError`, but an `ExecutionException` wrapping an `OutOfMemoryError`. This means the `mx.call(…)` operation failed with an `OutOfMemoryError` and `join` is reporting that to you. Of course, when you run three operations at the same time instead of one after another, you may need more memory while they are running.

Comment: You should look at the very last `Caused by` in your stacktrace. This will point you to the method that got the OOME, though it might not be the cause. You should first check that your code properly runs in sequential mode first. If it does, increasing memory might be enough.

Comment: @Holger The stack trace does not point me towards a particular 'mx.call(..)', just to the final get, or join, making this particularly difficult to trace down

Comment: @DidierL the stacktrace does not point me towards a particular method call just the get()/join() and the method which contains these futures. The code does properly run when sequential as well this was tested beforehand

Comment: @RyanM that’s because you have crippled the stack trace to the two entries showing where the `ExecutionException` has been constructed. That’s not where the `OutOfMemoryError` happened. You should look at last the “*Caused By*” section… As Didier L already said. And I already said that running three actions in parallel will need more memory than running the same three actions one after another. Well, they need the same memory, but at the same time, instead of potentially having garbage collections runs between them.

Comment: @RyanM can you please trying putting a failing psvm example here. That would really be helpful to find the targeted issue than setting up the stage first to generate this error. Though I uprooted would really like to see answers coming for this question.